# Can I change the Google Map Marker Color in the Apex Code?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to be able to change the "Nearby Accounts" that will pop up when you click on the button "Show Nearby Accounts" to be a different color than the account that you are originally looking at. Is this possible?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false"  standardStylesheets="false" cache="false" doctype="html-5.0" controller="NearbyAccountsController">
<html>

<head>
    <title>Nearby Accounts</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/> 

    <!-- jQuery + jQuery Mobile files -->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css')}" />

 <!-- Google Maps -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;   
            width: 100%;
        }
        #nearbyAccountsPage, .ui-content, #map_canvas { 
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            padding: 0; 
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        var map;
        var lat = {!account.Geolocation__Latitude__s};
        var lng = {!account.Geolocation__Longitude__s};
        var accountName = "{!account.Name}";
        var accountbillingstreet = "{!account.billingstreet}";
        var accountbillingcity = "{!account.billingcity}";
        var accountbillingstate = "{!account.billingstate}";
        var accountbillingpostalcode = "{!account.billingpostalcode}";

        $(document).on('pageshow', '#nearbyAccountsPage', function() {
            initGmap();
        });

        function initGmap() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            var mapOptions = {
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 13,

                // The following options are added to optimize for mobile screens. 
                mapTypeControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false, 
                scaleControl: false,
                rotateControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                }
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

            createMarkerAndInfoWindow(accountName, latlng);
        }

        function createMarkerAndInfoWindow(accountName, latlng) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                title: accountName,  
                map: map,
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<b>' + accountName + '<b>'                       
                });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        function getNearbyAccounts() {
            NearbyAccountsController.getNearbyAccounts(lat, lng, function (result, event) {
                if (event.status) {
                    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        var acctName = result[i].Name;
                        var acctBillingStreet = result[i].BillingStreet;
                        var acctBillingCity = result[i].BillingCity;
                        var acctBillingState = result[i].BillingState;
                        var acctBillingPostalCode = result[i].BillingPostalCode;
                        var acctLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].Geolocation__Latitude__s, result[i].Geolocation__Longitude__s);

                        createMarkerAndInfoWindow(acctName + '<br>' + acctBillingStreet + '<br>' + acctBillingCity + ', ' + acctBillingState + ' ' + acctBillingPostalCode, acctLatlng);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="nearbyAccountsPage">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>{!account.name}</h1>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" onclick="getNearbyAccounts();">Show Nearby</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Here is what it looks like now when you click on "Show Accounts." The red dot with the balloon that says United Hospital I want to be red, but all of the accounts surrounding it I want to be a different color.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answers to similar question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472957/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-google-maps-marker

(you're using v3 of the Google Maps API)

Direct link to documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#simple_icons)

You can either use different icon or really really draw a polygon, fill it with colors...

In your case I'd add some parameter to the function, maybe  `createMarkerAndInfoWindow(accountName, latlng, isPrimary)`. 
Or just pass the selected icon URL as 3rd param? `createMarkerAndInfoWindow(accountName, latlng, iconUri)`

The standard google marker icon will be somewhere here (warning, the page is LONG): https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/ and http://kml4earth.appspot.com/icons.html for example. It will probably be best to download the markers you want to static resource and store it within SF.

---

**Edit** to answer the comment

<grumpy rant>

I thought the hints are pretty clear but apparently it's a ["pls send teh codez"](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx) question... In future please show in the question what you've already tried to solve it / how you tried to apply the answers posted? The sidebar links at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask are bit aggressive but worth at least skimming through them...

</grumpy rant>

---

Modify that function so it looks similar to this:

```
function createMarkerAndInfoWindow(accountName, latlng, isPrimary) { // here
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        title: accountName,
        map: map,
// and here
        icon: isPrimary ? 'https://www.google.com/mapfiles/arrow.png' : 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/ylw-blank.png'
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<b>' + accountName + '<b>'
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Then look for instances where this function is called and add the parameter to the call.

1st time is inside `initGmap`:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
createMarkerAndInfoWindow(accountName, latlng, true);
```

2nd time is in the loop within `getNearbyAccounts()`:

```
createMarkerAndInfoWindow(acctName + '<br>' + acctBillingStreet + '<br>' + acctBillingCity + ', ' + acctBillingState + ' ' + acctBillingPostalCode, 
acctLatlng,
false);
```

Comment: i know how to change the icons, but when I change them, it changes it for all of them. What I want to see is that the account page they are when they click the "Show Nearby Accounts" I want that account marker to be in red and then when you click on the "Show Nearby" in the pop up window and the other accounts nearby pop up, I want those accounts to be in a different marker color.